# How to trigger Eloquent accessor after data have been pulled out

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.7

**Goal**

I want to be able to obfuscate my ids when sending JSON responses.

**I tryied**

Creating an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) like following:

```
public function getIdAttribute()
{
    return Crypt::encrypt($this->attributes['id']);
}
```

But this is ruining my relationship because (I learned with this) accessor are ran before querying...

**Question**

Is there any way to tell Eloquent to trigger the accessor after the result have been pulled out?

Answer (score 0):

Your accessor methods should never perform any operation on your properties. Instead, after the method is used, that is, the value of the ID is obtained, the encrypyt must be used.

Comment: That is my issue, I need to get a proxy method to listen "after data fetched". I managed to reach my goal, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative way to achieve what I intended, using [Response macros](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#response-macros):

*app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Crypt;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        JsonResponse::macro('secured', function () {
            $data = json_decode(json_encode(JsonResponse::getData()), $toArray = true);

            array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$value, $key) {
                if ($key === 'id') {
                    $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
                }
            });

            return $data;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Then, on any of your controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson() || $request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json(Post::all())->secured();
        }
    }
}
```

**Warning**

My database schema assumes every primary keys are named "id". Keep this in mind if you copy/paste this!

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options here..

1.

Instead of exposing your id, you can add a uuid field to your table, given that probably you want API consumers to be able to request/update/delete single objects that you need to identify?

That way you still have a unique identifier for you objects, but it can't be guessed.

2.

If you do not want to add extra fields and want to encrypt the id anyway, why not use a Resource Response object instead?

That will allow you to customize the response before returning it.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#resource-responses

So in your controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $posts = Post::all();

    return new PostResourceCollection($posts);
}
```

PostResource with id encryption

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;
use Crypt;

class PostResource extends Resource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => Crypt::encrypt($this->id]),
            'x' => $this->x,
            'y' => $this->y,
        ];
    }
}
```

PostResourceCollection which simply calls collection on PostResource

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class PostResourceCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return PostResource::collection($this->collection);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great @Robert, do you think I can use a trait to "industrialize" the process? Given the fact I will always have primary keys named "id", and I want to write the less ResourceCollection possible. Thank you.

Comment: You could use `$append` combined with a accessor? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json